# How to enable C++17 support in VSCode C++ Extension

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-code

I keep on getting error squiggles on std::string_view, but I am able to build just fine. Is there a way to tell intellisense or the C++ linter to use C++17?

The specific error I get is:

```
namespace "std" has no member "string_view"
```

Comment: never managed to get it working properly for C++17, same with VS

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48283026/3258851

Comment: Related: [How can I change the version of the C++ language standard used in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66680147/11107541)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This has become much easier now. Search for `cppstandard` in your vs code extension settings and choose the version of C++ you want the extension to use from the drop down.

[image]

In order to make sure your debugger is using the same version, make sure you have something like this for your `tasks.json`, where the important lines are the `--std` and the line after that defines the version.

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-I",
        "${fileDirname}",
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Note that if you're copying the above `tasks.json` directly, you'll need to have a folder named `out` in your workspace root.

Comment: You can also set it on a per-project basis https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_cc-configurations (this will create .vs_code/c_cpp_properties.json) in the project directory.

Comment: this does not work for `std::byte`. Still not found on VSCode and we're in 2022

Comment: I have the same problem with `std::filesystem`

Comment: `tasks.json` has no relation to the debugger

Comment: So I have to do this every time I start a new project?

Answer (score 20):

There's a posting in their GitHub issue tracker about this: [std::string_view intellisense missing (CMake, VC++ 2017)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1579).

In another issue, it is said that the extension defaults to C++17, but does not yet support all of C++17 features: [Setting C++ standard](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1468#issuecomment-358805332).

This is confirmed by [c_cpp_properties.json Reference Guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md), where an option is listed `cppStandard` which defaults to C++17. (To edit this file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type in `C/CPP: Edit Configurations`).

It appears, then, they just don't have full support yet.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I saw that github issue as well, but it seems like the responder to the initial post was not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Funny, mine is set at c++17, and still it's not finding `<optional>` :angry:

Comment: @DrumM That is exactly what I was looking for too, <optional>. I can compile, but it is annoying that VS Code gives me squiggles. Oh well.

Comment: UPDATE: I found a fix. I tried putting -std=C++17 in the "defaults" section of msvc.json per the recommendation of the "Setting C++ standard" link and it didn't work. Problem was I put it in the wrong file. I changed the file in .vscode folder in my Windows' user folder, but I am using VS Code in WSL, so I had to edit the msvc.json file in my WSL user folder's .vscode folder. When I did that the red squiggly went away!

Comment: I haven't seen any doc about the `msvc.json` file, only the `c_cpp_properties.json`. Why is the latter not sufficient?

Answer (score 7):

Just an updated. I got this issue as well.

I solve it by adding `c_cpp_properties.json`

1. Ctrl + Shift + P  then select `C/C++:Edit Configurations (JSON)`
2. Adjust the content for `cStandard` and `cppStandard`:

   ```
       "cStandard": "gnu17",
       "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
   ```

Comment: It did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

**For people trying out on Linux and having GCC 7.5.0 installed, this worked for me.**
Do these two steps to enable the linter to acknowledge the c++17 writings and for the compiler to pick up the c++17.

1. Open up the `C/C++:Edit Configurations (JSON)`, and change the default values for these two fields to:

> "cStandard": "gnu18", "cppStandard": "gnu++17",

2. Open up the `tasks.json` file inside `.vscode` directory and add the following statements to the `args` key:

> "--std", "c++17"

Answer (score 2):

If you're unable to enable even after trying the solutions by [@Marc.2377](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415248/14631939) and [@W Kenny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372220/14631939), do the following

1. Open `tasks.json` in the `.vscode` folder
2. Add `"--std","c++17"` under `"args:"`
3. Save `tasks.json`

Comment: This will change how the compiler works, not the linter

Comment: Worked for me. Linux, VS Code, C++17. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things I have found probably a solution for people using CMake and willing to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

I just put the following line at the beginning of my `CMakeLists.txt`

`set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`

You can check your c++ version by doing:
`cout << __cplusplus ;`
and the 3rd and 4th number gives you the version of c++ you are using.

For example:

`cout << __cplusplus ;`

`201703`

means you are using c++ 17

and

`cout << __cplusplus ;`

`201402`

means you are using c++ 14

I think that there must be an easier solution but I could not find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to set `cppStandard` to `gnu++17` in `c_cpp_properties.json` mentioned in other posts, you need to change the `__cplusplus`-define to the corresponding value (e.g. `201703L`)

Like that:

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "configurations": [
    {
      // ...
      "cStandard": "gnu17",
      "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
      "defines": [
        // ...
        "__cplusplus=201703L"
        // ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This should not be needed / this macro should be set automatically if the `-std` argument is set correctly; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089319/is-there-a-standard-definition-for-cplusplus-in-c14

Answer (score 0):

I have tried editing the settings of `C_Cpp>Default: Cpp Standard` and `C Standard` to specify them as `C++17 standard`. However, that did not work.

Then I found a `.vscode` folder in my project directory with a `c_cpp_properties.json` file. In there I found settings that I had not edited, where I specified to use the `C++11 standard`. When I changed it, I found that the problem was gone.

If you find that the answer above doesn't work, maybe we made the same mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Check your version of g++ using `g++ --version` on the command line. If it is like version 6 or 7 then you need to update to a newer version with mingw. I used [mysys2](https://www.msys2.org/) to do this and now I do not have the same problem.