# Syntax error highlighting missing from VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Today VSCode started acting weird - it started to not highlight any syntax errors I had.
Example:

```
void foo() {
    int num1 = 5;
    hello world 123 "gsjke"
}
```

In the above code, VSCode shows no syntax errors, when I build the file, it works as expected and terminates with exit code -1.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679446/vscode-ide-does-not-highlight-errors-in-c-code-anymore) post on this site that had the exact same problem as me, I tried the posted solution, but it didn't work for me.
I tried reinstalling the extensions, deleting the `settings.json` file, and reinstalling VSCode.

Nothing works.

I use VSCode version 1.83.1 (user), I have the c/c++ extensions.

Edit: user4581301 suggested that I should include my `c_cpp_properties.json` file, here it is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Useful search term: Dogfooding

Comment: I don't have VSCode here at work to test that but did you check your `c_cpp_properties.json` to see if intellisense was properly configured.

Comment: In order for folk out here to offer verifiable answers you'll have to add the VS Code configuration files, specifically c_cpp_properties.json in this case, to the question. This will allow us to see the configuration and either show you what needs to be fixed directly or perhaps to ask for more clarifications.

Comment: you can try `notskm.clang-tidy`, `usernamehw.errorlens` vscode extensions and `clang-tidy` (LLVM) be sure add `clang-tidy` executable into `PATH`