# MinGW defaults C++14 instead of C++17 in VS Code IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I am setting up the environment to learn C++. I am using VS Code as an IDE and MinGW as a Compiler. but it

seems that i can't run C++17 code without alot of errors. So i used the following code to check C++ version

```
#include<iostream>
int main() {
if (__cplusplus == 201703L)
  std::cout << "C++17";
else if (__cplusplus == 201402L)
  std::cout << "C++14";
else if (__cplusplus == 201103L)
  std::cout << "C++11";
else if (__cplusplus == 199711L)
  std::cout << "C++98";
else
  std::cout << "pre-standard C++";
}
```

it returns C++14. I googled it but ended up with "Change your IDE" which i cant because i have a very low end Laptop which can bearly handle VS Code without screen freezing. I have also seen the "g++ -std=c++17 file.cpp" tip which didnt work either. I would appreciate it if someone can help me without changing the IDE.

(i have also downloaded the C++ package from the Microsoft Visual Studio installer which was around 6GB and used "CL" as a Compiler in VS Code but it returns C++98 when running the above code for some reason.)

Comment: It looks like you may need to run the Visual Studio installer(I can't remember if the VS installer was also used to install VS Code - I currently use both) to install C++ 17. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Comment: How does your VSCode task configuration JSON file look like? Did you specify the `-std=c++17` compiler flag there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable C++17 support in VSCode C++ Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension)

Comment: Please add the version of g++ provided by your mingw installation. You should be able to get this  by invoking g++ on the command line with the -v option. If this returns something in the 6s or 7s you'll want to update the compiler.

Comment: @Skewjo i followed that exact tutorial which didn't help.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ i thought that line can be used in the cmd only, Can you clarify more on how can i adjust my task.json file to adabt ?

Comment: My G++ version is 8.1.0

Comment: The link unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page [__cplusplus conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160). By default, the compiler MSVC always define the macro `__cplusplus` to `197711L`, thus it does not conform to the standard. Add the flag `/Zc:__cplusplus` explicitly to enable the conformant behaviour. Not that the `/permissive-` does not affect the `/Zc:__cplusplus` flag implicitly (contrary to most other conformance `/Zc` flags).

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio Code sitting atop the mingw port of g++, not Visual Studio.