# How do i set a C++ language standard in Visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I'm trying to follow the C++ tutorial at [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-choosing-a-language-standard/) but it doesn't have the steps for Visual Studio Code. I installed the gcc compiler on linux using apt install gcc and tried running the C++17 code on that website with G++ but i keep getting errors. Could you help me out here? is there a setting I need to change in VS code?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension) help?

Comment: Select cmd-shift P (mac) ctrl-shift-P (windows/linux) and type "C++ Edit". You should be presented with two options: a UI editor and a json editor. Select whichever you're comfortable with. The language level specifier is one of the options, and will update the cpp_properties.json file for the project.

Comment: @WhozCraig changing `cpp_properties.json` does not help you compiling a C++ program

Comment: read the docs of VSC about C++

Comment: @PaulSanders I'll try it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually all i needed to do was to make use of compiler arguments which could be set using C++ edit configurations using the vs code command palette.