# Class "std::map" has no member "contains" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++20

When I am using `map.contains()` in my C++ code using Visual Studio Code I get the following message:

> class "std::map<int, int, std::less,
> std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>>" has no member "contains"

Thankfully, my code compiles when I run `g++ -std=c++20 test.cc -o test`, but VSCode keeps telling me there's a problem, which is quite irritating. This is my code:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int, int> m;

bool contains_key(int idx) { return m.contains(idx); }
```

Has anyone had the same issue and knows how to fix it?

Comment: [map::contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) was only added in C++20, so it won't compile unless you configure vscode to use that language revision.

Comment: look in `cpp_properties.json`

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension) on enabling C++17 support should also guide you to enabling C++20.

Answer (score 7):

`std::map::contains()` was introduced in C++20, which is why it works when you configure your compile to use C++20.

For earlier C++ versions, you will have to use `std::map::find()` or `std::map::count()` instead:

```cpp
bool contains_key(int idx) { return m.find(idx) != m.end(); }
```

```cpp
bool contains_key(int idx) { return m.count(idx) > 0; }
```