# How to disable warning for structured bindings available with C++17 in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, warnings

[image]

I want to disable this annoying warning. how?

I use vscode.

```
structured bindings only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
```

Comment: This may answer your question: [How to enable C++17 support in VSCode C++ Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension)

Answer (score 6):

According to the [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), you could set the `cppStandard` to `c++17` in your `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
"cppStandard": "c++17",
```