# "no != operator matches these operands" error in Visual Studio Code with a working example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Lately Intellisense in my VSC started giving me the above error in a working code.
If I write:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string str = "Hello";
    for(auto c : str) {}
    return 0;
}
```

then VSC highlights the for loop saying: "no != operator matches these operands".

I tried compiling the code outside VSC and it worked without any problems. I also tried downgrading the VSC's version, but the problem still persist. I suspect the problem may be in some external tool the VSC uses, but I have got no clue as of what it is.

I'm using the below configuration:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            ],
            "defines": [
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**EDIT:**
More info:

- I've worked with C++20 for a long time in VSCode and I have never had such a problem before,
- The bug persists even when I purge the VSCode installation and put a fresh install of both VSC and a C/C++ extension (the one which provides Intellisense service in VSC)
- My VSC is in version 1.78 and the C/C++ extension is v1.16.0

Comment: What C++ Standard version is the IntelliSence (not the compiler settings) part of VS-Code set to?

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried with c++20 and gnu++20. Both gives the same results. And Intellisense is set to "gcc-x64"

Comment: make sure your linting/intellisense is using c++20 aswell

Comment: Maybe try uninstall it completely and then reinstall. [How to enable C++17 support in VSCode C++ Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397233/how-to-enable-c17-support-in-vscode-c-extension)

Comment: @Jason this bug exists even with fresh install of both VSCode and C/C++ extension for it.

Comment: @Felix.leg Did you try the solutions given in the duplicates?

Comment: @Felix.leg You can vote to reopen your own question you know.